# How do I connect Local Kafka Cluster to Local Mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, apache-kafka

I am currently working on a small  project where I need to connect a kafka cluster to mongodb so that the mesages published to kafka topic gets stored in the mongodb database. I currently have a local kafka cluster, a springboot producer publishing messages to a topic and a springboot consumer consuming those messages locally. I also have installed mongodb compass locally...i have been looking at tutorials and what i have figured out is that i have to use some kind of sink connector(mongodb connector) for what i want to do but most of the examples are based on mongodb atlas and confluent or aws managed kafka...is there any good tutorials i can follow to learn how to do on local kafka cluster and local mongodb or if any one of u can explain me what to do, i will greatly appreciate it.. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> most of the examples are based on mongodb atlas and confluent or aws managed kafka..

Remove any access keys or authentication, and simply modify the `bootstrap.servers` property + Mongo connection string, and any tutorial you find should work with your local installations

AFAICT, the Docker example in the documentation does not use any cloud services

https://docs.mongodb.com/kafka-connector/current/kafka-docker-example/